# Reading From a Stream using DotSpatial

Tags: dotspatial

Is it possible, using DotSpatial, to read data from a stream (or set of streams) instead of from a specific file?  I was hoping that I could point it at the encompassing ZIP file and it'd just work.

I've looked at the `Shapefile.Open()` and `Shapefile.OpenFile()` methods, but there doesn't seem to be anything to open ZIP files or multiple streams.

Comment: Hi! I'm looking for the same thing, and couldn't find anything online. Did you manage to figure out if it's possible to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @Raj, I can't remember how I solved this one.  I've not done much GIS stuff since this contract 2 years ago.

Comment: That's okay. I'll keep looking around. Thanks for the quick response though!